# how to select a csv file automatically from a specified path in c#

Tags: c#, file, csv

I am a newbie to programming so i am hoping support for my problems from all my friends
This is the problem
I have used the loation as 2DB to read a csv file.It works well when I give the file name also But I want to give only  location and program needs to select the file

string path = "G:\kaash\2DB\";

```
        string[] row_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(""+path+", *.csv");
        string[] data_col = null;
```

Comment: Is the file name going to be same all the time?

Comment: no machan it will change time to time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you to find all .csv files as a list of strings from the specified directory.

```
string path = @"G:\kaash\2DB\";
List<string> csvIn2DB = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csv", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
```

By modifying the search pattern you can locate your files more specifically. You can change the `SearchOption` to `AllDirectories` if you want to extend the search to inner folders of the specified directory.

Let you need to get all your .csv file names follows the pattern "FILECSV_xxxxxx.csv", then the search pattern will be like this: `FILECSV_*.csv`

Comment: Thanks machan you have really solved my problem Thanks alot...by the way your name may be unluckey but your answers bring lucky to people like me ... thanks again..

Comment: Cool... Happy to help you